# How to show div when media is print, hide at all other times?

Tags: css

I want to use this to print only the `#section-to-print`:

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #section-to-print {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

How do I extend this to hide the `#section-to-print` when it is being displayed on the screen?  In other words, it would only be visible when the media is print.

Comment: outside the media query set it to hidden...

Comment: I see how to do this for just screen, but not for all types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it to visibility: hidden, then @media print can override it.

```
#section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
    visibility: hidden;
}
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #section-to-print {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```